# Free Pascal can't find entry point for dll

Tags: delphi, dll, pascal, freepascal

I am complete new to pascal.
I want to call my function in .dll file in free pascal and I get following error when I run the project:

The procedure entry point GetProcAddress could not be located in the dynamic link library HNLib.dll.

here is the code:

```
Program Test;
function GetProcAddress : Integer; cdecl; external 'HNLib.dll';
function GetProcAddress : Single; cdecl; external 'HNLib.dll';
procedure GetProcAddress( X : Single); cdecl; external 'HNLib.dll';
procedure GetProcAddress; cdecl; external 'HNLib.dll';
begin
  GetProcAddress( 5.5 );
  readln;
end.
```

.pas file and dll are in one directory.

Please Help ME!

Comment: Obvious first question: Is there *supposed* to be a function named `GetProcAddress` in your DLL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` is not what you seem to think it is; it's purpose is to locate named procedures or functions in a DLL and return the address of that function so it can be called from your code. You have to first use `LoadLibrary` to load the dynamic link library (DLL) into memory, and then pass a handle to that DLL as the first parameter of `GetProcAddress` and the name of the function whose address you want as the second parameter. If the function can be found in the DLL, it's address is returned, and you can use that address to call the function.

(In addition, `GetProcAddress` is pretty Windows-specific, and the majority of functions in the WinAPI are `stdcall` and not `cdecl`. Unless you have documentation saying that the functions are using the `cdecl` calling convention, you should probably use `stdcall`.)

You would also need at least the `Windows` unit in your uses clause, since that's where `GetProcAddress` and `LoadLibrary` are declared.

See the WinAPI documentation on [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

For a beginning programmer, you'll probably find it easier to use static linking of the functions instead of dynamic (which you get with `GetProcAddress`). An example of static linking would be (untested !!!- just a quick code example, since I don't have 'HNLib.DLL' to link against):

```
// Your Dll import unit
unit MyDllProcs;

interface

  function GetIntCalcResult(const IntVal: Integer); 

implementation

  function GetIntCalcResult(const IntVal: Integer); stdcall; external 'HNLib.dll';

end.

// Your own app's code
program Test;

interface

  uses MyDllProcs;

implementation

function DoSomethingWithDll(const ValueToCalc: Integer): Integer;        
begin
  Result := GetIntCalcResult(ValueToCalc);
end;

begin
  WriteLn('DoSomethingWithDll returned ', DoSomethingWithDll(10));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Note that when statically linking DLL functions like this, your DLL must be available when your app starts, and the function must be contained in that DLL; if not, your application won't load.

Also, note that you can't typically have multiple functions with the same name in the DLL, as there's no information available to use to figure which one to load when the load is being done. Each should have a separate, distinct name or the loading will probably fail.

Comment: +1 I don't get why you've gotten a -1, this is perfectly explained, but I would split the "myddlprocs" unit code from "program" code, otherwise it can get harder to understand, but besides that, it's perfect!

Comment: +1 No idea why anyone could downvote this. My only comments would be that the second paragraph hints that one might guess the calling convention. One should always be sure what the calling convention is. And a minor nitpick, what you call static linking is officially known as implicit linking but I'm sure everyone is getting tired of me pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks. Dorin, I did split the two into separate units (`unit MyDllProcs` and `program Test`). David, I accept the nitpick, but I think both terms are acceptable (Delphi docs for ages referred to `static` and `dynamic` linking to DLLs; I don't know if they're written that way now, but for people who've been with D/C++Builder will be familiar with the terminology). I've no idea about the downvote either, but I have suspicions (the usual one).

Comment: In FPC it is customary to use the unit dynlibs to load libraries and get symbols. It is more portable than Windows.

Comment: @Marco, thanks. I don't use FPC, so I didn't have that info. The question was about using GetProcAddress (according to the code, anyway), so that's what I answered. I'll file away `dynlibs` for future reference, though.

Comment: It was just FYI. The signatures are basically the same, except that it uses a locally defined handle type. One of the problems with emulating windows libs is that Windows uses THandle for stuff that has different handletypes (and -sizes) on non Windows. It's a pretty old situation, iirc originally devised for Jedi-SDL

Comment: I know, and appreciate it - always like new info. :) I think Delphi XE2's Windows unit fixes a bunch of the incorrect uses of THandle (finally). I seem to recall several questions related to compiler errors for code using THandle that worked in earlier versions but were failing to compile in XE2.